# Microsoft Live Connect OAuth API stopped returning email in user information

Tags: php, oauth, microsoft-live-connect

I am using PHP Microsoft Live Oauth Signing using this library https://github.com/siftware/live-connect it used to work well, but now i noticed that once i login and request profile information i get no info only user id.

With my testing live login i should get at least email, but i dont get it from live api.

- I am requesting neccessary scopes:
  $liveConnect->setScopes("wl.emails, wl.signin, wl.basic");
- I checked my live profile on https://account.microsoft.com/ and it is true that i have empty name there, but the email is filled and should be available (and in the past it worked as i said).
- I checked apps privacy settings for my live account and the certain web app and i see that the permissions were requested and granted successfully. That means following permissions are granted:

  - Access your email addresses
  - View your profile info and contact list
  - Sign in automatically

So why the live oauth api stopped sending email information of my account?

Maybe the api changed and the change is not reflected in the library, i will check it - it seems it is still actual.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that once i set first name and last name in the profile info on https://account.microsoft.com/ api starts to send all information about profile (name and email also).

Before it was sending email also when the name was empty. So it is probably some internal API change.